# Let’s change “general references” to “databases”

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons

#### Proposal

In help texts, close reasons, and similar, **replace *general reference* with *database***. If space permits, elaborate that *database* means *dictionary, thesaurus, conjugation tables, or similar.*

For example and most importantly, change our favourite custom close reason to:

> This site is about the usage and rules of the German language. It is not well-suited to replace a database, such as a dictionary, thesaurus, or conjugation table. If you have already consulted such sources and still have questions, please edit your question to explain what you found and why it did not help. See [this post on Meta](//german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/628) for more information.

#### Rationale

*General references* is open to interpretation and we often dispute the exegesis of this term, e.g., [here](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1303/2594) and [here](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/819/2594). I cannot remember a discussions on this topic where somebody argued that non-database references (such as grammar books or encyclopædias) should be considered for the purpose of closing or similar. Also, this is a remnant of a close reason that is long gone from most of the rest of the network.

On the other hand, *database* seems to capture exactly why we are closing questions with the above reason: This site is not suited as a database, i.e., as a collection of a huge number of strictly structured snippets of information – that’s what dictionaries, thesauri, conjugation tables, or similar are for. Or with other words: A question should be closed all we can answer is essentially reproducing an existing database item.

#### Voting

- Use votes on the question to indicate general agreement or disagreement with the proposal.
- Use answers to provide critique or suggest improvements to the proposal.
- Use votes on answers to indicate agreement or disagreement.

---

#### Vorschlag

*General reference (allgemeines Nachschlagewerk)* soll in Hilfetexten, Schließgründen u. Ä. durch *database (Datenbank)* ersetzt werden.
Wenn möglich soll ausgeführt werden, dass mit Letzterem Wörterbücher, Thesauri, Konjugationstabellen u. Ä. gemeint sind.

Zum Beispiel und vor allem, soll unser Lieblingsschließgrund lauten:

> This site is about the usage and rules of the German language. It is not well-suited to replace a database, such as a dictionary, thesaurus, or conjugation table. If you have already consulted such sources and still have questions, please edit your question to explain what you found and why it did not help. See [this post on Meta](//german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/628) for more information.

#### Begründung

Es ist nicht jedem klar wie *general references* zu interpretieren ist und wir haben häufig Diskussionen um die Auslegung dieses Begriffs, z. B. [hier](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1303/2594) und [hier](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/819/2594).
Ich kann mich jedoch nicht daran erinnern, dass sich jemals jemand dafür ausgesprochen hat, dass Nachschlagbarkeit in etwas anderes als Datenbanken (z. B. Grammatiken oder Enzyklopädien) hinreichend zum Schließen einer Frage sei. Außerdem handelt es sich bei dieser Formulierung um ein Überbleibsel eines Schließgrunds, den der überwiegende Rest des Stack-Exchange-Netzwerks schon längst abgeschafft hat.

Hingegen scheint mir *database* bzw. *Datenbank* genau wiederzuspiegeln, weswegen wir Fragen mit dem obigen Grund schließen: Diese Seite ist nicht geeignet als Datenbank, d.h., als Sammlung einer großen Anzahl von fest strukturierten Informationsschnipseln – dies können Wörterbücher, Thesauri, Konjugationstabellen, usw. besser.
Mit anderen Worten: Eine Frage sollte geschlossen werden, wenn die einzige Antwort, die wir geben können, im Wesentlichen ein existierender Datenbankeintrag ist.

#### Abstimmen

- Stimmt für oder gegen die Frage, um Eure Zustimmung oder Ablehnung zu obigem Vorschlag auszudrücken.
- Nutzt Antworten um den Vorschlag zu kritisieren oder Verbesserungen vorzuschlagen.
- Nutzt Stimmen für oder gegen Antworten, um Eure Zustimmung oder Ablehnung auszudrücken.

Comment: We should perhaps include somewhere that any such database should be easily accessible by everybody, and that Wikipedia or German Language SE are **not** such a database.

Comment: Well, in the later case, that would be a duplicate. I do not know how many people would mistake Wikipedia for a database. Either way, it should be more easy to draw the line for *database* than for *general reference.*

Comment: Ganz richtig, aber wir hatten das durchaus, dass ein Wikipedia Artikel reichte, um eine Frage hier mit Close zu voten. Solche Benutzer gibt's durchaus.

Comment: @Takkat: Deswegen ja auch dieser Vorschlag. Solche Fragen werden geschlossen, aber wann immer man mal nachfragt, sieht niemand ein Problem damit – ich vermute als, dass das das alte Problem ist, dass Nutzer denken dass sie etwas schließen müssen, sobald ein Schließgrund das sagt, und nicht weil sie tatsächlich generell diese Meinung vertreten.

Comment: Ich halte das auch für eine gute Idee - mein Upvote hat Dein Proposal schon lange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the issues we have with an umbrella term I propose we ditch *general reference* alltogether and just say what reference we mean:

> This site is about the usage and rules of the German language. It is not well-suited to replace a dictionary, thesaurus, or conjugation table. If you have already consulted such sources and still have questions, please edit your question to explain what you found and why it did not help. See [this post on Meta](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/628) for more information.

I can't think of any other additional reference that would fit to such a canned close reason anyway and if we are faced with a question that needs to be closed for a reason not covered we should make use of a **custom close reason** (in fact we use custom closures much too rarely).

Comment: *if we are faced with the rare case of a question that needs to be closed because of an otherwise lack of research we can always use a custom close reason* –  Can you give an example for a question that you think should be closed *only* for lack of research?

Comment: LOL - mal sehen, es wird schwierig, weil diese Fragen oft auch ein Dupe sind oder ich sie eigentlich gar nicht geschlossen hätte. Einzelne schludrige Grammatikfragen vielleicht, aber das ist schon selten.

Comment: *Schludrige Fragen* hört sich nach etwas an, das man auch legitim als *unclear* schließen kann.

Comment: yepp - kann man - oft wäre *unclear* viel besser als *general reference*, eben weil es unklar bleibt, welche Fragen die Wörterbücher offen ließen.

Comment: Naja, wenn Wörterbücher die Fragen nicht beantworten, dann trifft es *general reference* schon ganz gut, weil es eben auch beinhaltet: »If you have already consulted such sources and still have questions, please edit your question to explain what you found and why it did not help.« Aber Du sprachst ja von Fällen, wo es eben nicht die Wörterbuchrecherche ist die fehlt oder unzureichend dargelegt ist.

Comment: Neeeee, da reden wir jetzt völlig aneinander vorbei. Ich meine hypothetische Fragen, die nach Wegfall der Bezeichung *Datenbank* außer Wörterbuch, Thesaurus oder Konjugationstabelle dann noch übrig blieben. Weil das vielleicht gar keine sind, ist es ein Argument dafür, dass wir die Bezeichnung *Datenbank* gar nicht brauchen.

Comment: schludrig klingt eher nach edit

Comment: Ich würde die ziemlich spezifische Konjugationstabelle durch ein Grammatikbuch gerne ersetzt sehen. Nicht alles, was eine Grammatikreferenz beantwortet hätte, findet sich in Konjugationstabellen. (Wobei mir gerade beim schreiben kommt, dass das umgekehrt ja auch gilt.)

Comment: @Jan: das Grammatikbuch hatten wir schon vor Jahren verworfen. Ich meine, weil man dort zwar die Regel findet, aber konkrete Fragen doch nicht beantworten kann.

Comment: Vielleicht bin ich einfach zu voreingenommen von den vielen [tag:word-order]-Fragen, die sich vom Grammatikbuch beantworten ließen, von der Konjugationstabelle aber eher weniger …

Comment: @Jan: Ein Ziel der vorgeschlagenen Änderung ist, Grammatikbücher aus der Liste der Referenzen, die wir nicht ersetzen wollen, zu streichen. Nebenbei gibt es eh nur endlich viele einfache Fragen, die man zur Satzordnung stellen kann, und wahrscheinlich wurden alle schon einmal gestellt und nicht geschlossen. Und wenn der Fragesteller nicht klarstellt, was er nicht versteht, können wir immer noch als *unclear* schließen.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree because the term database is also ambiguous and does not necessarily imply a structured text IMHO. For me personally it is rather a very technical term, this is probably related to my profession as IT guy, however I never heard the word database as a super term for a dictionary nor for a thesaurus in a non technical context.
If it is necessary to replace reference I would like to suggest:

> dictionary :: Nachschlagewerk

With dictionary I associate a text which has a structured lookup table or index which helps to find a explanation regardless what its purpose is.

Comment: *Dictionary* does not work very well since it does not cover thesauri and conjugation tables in English very well. We might use something like *dictionary-like resource,* but that’s rather clunky. Another alternative might be to avoid an umbrella term altogether and just say *dictionaries, thesauri, and conjugation tables.* — *Nachschlagewerk* is definitely broader than what I have in mind (and than the English *dictionary*). I would consider an encyclopædia a *Nachschlagewerk.*

Comment: *a structured text* – I don’t exactly know what your understanding of *structured text,* but I would associate this with textbooks, laws, and similar – not with dictionaries, which do not contain larger portions of text.

Comment: I agree, dictionary is probably not as broad as Nachschlagewerk but I am really not this English freak to judge it finally and I would favor it over database. With structured text I mean a text which has well defined order and clear definition of its purpose regardless of the length of its text entries. I tried to use it for the same meaning for what you tried to explain why is database a good word for you.

Comment: Maybe it is worth to ask the whole topic in the English Language StackExchange (Meta or not).